# Exact sequence for the Spin group

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I read that the $Spin(n)$ is the double cover of $SO(n)$ such that the following sequence is exact
$$ 1 \to \mathbb{Z}_2 \to Spin(n) \to SO(n) \to 1 $$
**My first question** is what information does this sequence exactly convey? I am familiar with the exact sequences one encounters in algebraic topology, for example Meyer-Vietoris type of sequences where I get information on how to compute homology groups of a more complicated space from easier ones, but I am not sure what I should understand from the sequence above.

**My second question** is, that since $Spin(n)$ is the double cover of $SO(n)$ is it true that $Spin(n) \cong SO(n)/\mathbb{Z}_2$ just las $SU(2) \cong SO(3)\mathbb{Z}_2$?

Comment: You have it the wrong way round. ${\rm SO}(n) \cong {\rm Spin}(n)/C_2$.

Comment: I will correct it but what is $C_2$?

Comment: It's $\mathbb{Z}_2$. (The notation emphasizes that we're thinking about $\mathbb{Z}_2$ as the cyclic group of order $2$, as opposed to e.g. as a finite field, and it's also less ambiguous in that it's harder to confuse with the $2$-adic integers.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a lot of information from this sequence by combining it with other background knowledge. For example, once you know that $Spin(n)$ is (for $n \ge 3$) even the universal cover of $SO(n)$, you know that the representation theory of $Spin(n)$ is the same as the representation theory of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(n)$, and that among these representations the representations of $SO(n)$ are the ones where this central copy of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ acts trivially. The ones that don't have this property include the [spin representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_representation), which describe [spinors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinor). Note that when $n = 3$ we have $Spin(3) \cong SU(2)$.

On the algebraic topology side, because $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is central, this sequence actually [deloops](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/delooping) to a [fiber sequence](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/fiber+sequence)

$$BSpin(n) \to BSO(n) \to B^2 \mathbb{Z}_2$$

which turns out to tell you that an oriented smooth manifold has a [spin structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_structure) if and only if a certain characteristic class in $H^2(-, \mathbb{Z}_2)$ vanishes. This class turns out to be the [Stiefel-Whitney class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiefel%E2%80%93Whitney_class) $w_2$.

Comment: Hi, the last part you mention is very interesting, i.e. when a smooth manifold admits a spin structure. Can you expand a bit on this or provide some targeted reference? I am a physicist and I am quite curious to know when I can define spinor bundles in my manifolds.

Comment: @Marion: looking up the term "spin geometry" will get you a lot of references.